# Parent:: or $this->

Tags: php, oop

I am starting a new project and i am not sure whats the best/right why of getting the parents methods?

should it be done this why

```
class ControllerForum extends ControllerAbstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function actionViewThread($threadName, (int) $threadId)
    {
        $threadModel = $this->getModel('ModelThread');
    }
}
```

or this why

```
class ControllerForum extends ControllerAbstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function actionViewThread($threadName, (int) $threadId)
    {
        $threadModel = parent::getModel('ModelThread');
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do two different things:

When you call `$this->method()` you are calling the `method()` defined in your own child class (ControllerForum in this case).

When you call `parent::method()` you are calling the one defined in the parent class (ControllerAbstract).

So if we, let's say, define getModel in both ControllerAbstract and ControllerForum (override) then calling one or another will execute different code. I would use the inherited method (the first form) unless you need specific behaviour.

**EDIT**: @Chris It's inheritance, it means that the child class (that extends the parent class) will have the methods and properties of the parent class. When you use `$this->method()` you don't call the parent method, you call the method of the current class inherited from the parent class. See [PHP 5 inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: Okay because I have been people use $this->method() when calling a parent method before. (i have seen it done that why in many frameworks) The method getModel will only be in the ControllerAbstract and never in the child class. so i would still use parent:: ?

Comment: So even if the child does not have the same methods and properties its safe to use parent::method.

Comment: You use parent:: when you explicitly want to call the parent version of any method in your inherited class.

Answer (score -1):

always code depend on the need

if you are able to create object of class then normally we are use first way

```
$threadModel = $this->getModel('ModelThread');
```

the second approach is use when we want to call function without object

```
$threadModel = parent::getModel('ModelThread');
```

so it's based on need

Thanks